# Adding Array to Custom Google Apps Script for Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a bit of code to use a ZIP code to find the county and I want to be able to use the function as an array formula so that I can add it to a sheet for form responses.

I tried to look up how to make the function work with an array formula but I don't know enough to apply it.

Is it possible to make this code work as an array formula?

Sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S-TVchlE1sFTIOrbOL-v_N3LJJHLAHLJHkUtVpFeZok/edit#gid=0

```
/*
 *
 * Google Maps Formulas for Google Sheets
 *
 * Written by Amit Agarwal
 *
 * Web: https://www.labnol.org/google-maps-sheets-200817
 *
 */

const md5 = (key = "") => {
  const code = key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");
  return Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, key)
    .map((char) => (char + 256).toString(16).slice(-2))
    .join("");
};

const getCache = (key) => {
  return CacheService.getDocumentCache().get(md5(key));
};

const setCache = (key, value) => {
  const expirationInSeconds = 6 * 60 * 60; // max is 6 hours
  CacheService.getDocumentCache().put(md5(key), value, expirationInSeconds);
};
/**
 * Get the county name of an address on Google Maps.
 *
 * =GOOGLEMAPS_COUNTY("10 Hanover Square, NY")
 *
 * @param {String} address The address to lookup.
 * @return {String} The county of the address.
 * @customFunction
 */
const GOOGLEMAPS_COUNTY = (address) => {
  if (!address) {
    throw new Error("No address specified!");
  }
  if (address.map) {
    return address.map("administrative_area_level_2");
  }
  const key = ["administrative_area_level_2", address].join(",");
  const value = getCache(key);
  if (value !== null) return value;
  const { results: [data = null] = [] } = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
  if (data === null) {
    throw new Error("Address not found!");
  }
  const [{ long_name } = {}] = data.address_components.filter(
    ({ types: [level] }) => {
      return level === "administrative_area_level_2";
    }
  );
  if (!long_name) {
    throw new Error("County not found!");
  }
  const answer = `${long_name}`;
  setCache(key, answer);
  return answer;
};
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, the following sample script is your expected goal?

#### Sample script:

Please add the following script to your current script and save it.

```
const GOOGLEMAPS_COUNTY_ARRAY = values => values.map(r => r.map(c => c.toString() ? GOOGLEMAPS_COUNTY(c) : null));
```

When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=GOOGLEMAPS_COUNTY_ARRAY(A2:A)` to a cell.

#### Testing:

When your sample Spreadsheet is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)